# Unable to Access WP Admin or Login buttons after Migration

Tags: admin, wp-admin, login, permissions

After migrating from IIS server over to CentOS, I am having a hard time logging into my admin. When I did manage to login it said the User had no permission to login into WP Admin so it was the permissions.

I went over and reset usermeta and user tables with fresh new information I copied from a clean install and I did login, however all the plugin settings, posts etc were assosiated with the old admin account.

Any ideas? Right now I cant even show the input fields on the login button and wp-admin isnt working either.

Any ideas? Suggestions? Troubleshooting tips?

Comment: Forgot to mention the url, it is:

http://essex-restaurants.co.uk/

Comment: how did you migrate?

Comment: Hi Mark,

I have used phpmyadmin at first and the second try via mysql workbench on our IIS server.

I have tried setting correct permissions for the users in _usermeta and _users and still either no permission issue or blank login inputs and wp-admin page.

The database version between old server and new reseller plan are .5 versions (our server is at 4.5.x and reseller on 4.0.x)

Comment: what about plugins, did you try to turn them off, switch to a default theme?